# How to bootstrap an MSI to Esri .NET Add-in

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, add-in

I support an old COM extension to ArcMap built using ArcObjects, and I'm exploring the possibility of [porting it to an Add-in](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_migrate_from_COM_components_to_add_ins/0001000003z6000000/).  The main benefit I'm seeking with the add-in is its ease of deployment: the ability to place the deployed addinx file in a networked folder. Consequently I'm trying to avoid an installer. This particular extension makes extensive use of `SqlGeometry` and other SQL CLR types, and the current installer bootstraps [the MSI for those types](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35580).  Is there a way to perform something similar with an add-in, or are we stuck with the COM extension and associated installer?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an MSI that contains the Esri addin and anything else you need.

Have the MSI output its content (i.e. the .esriaddin file) in a temp folder then have a custom action in the MSI that calls this file. The regular Esri installer will be launched.

Make sure to also configure an action so that the addin is removed from ArcMap when you uninstall the MSI.

Comment: I'm looking to avoid the installer altogether. I've updated my question to explicate this.